# How to execute a process with CAP_SYS_RESOURCE

Tags: posix, linux-capabilities

I'm using Linux POSIX mqueue implementation, and I have a problem.
For current kernel, the max message size is 1MB, but I need to have no limit.

[`man mq_overview`](https://linux.die.net/man/7/mq_overview) says that if the process is privileged (a process that has `CAP_SYS_RESOURCE` capability) it has no limits.
I thought that a process executed by root was already privileged, but I'm still getting "message too long" error (my message has 2MB).

How can I add `CAP_SYS_RESOURCE` capability to the process?

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if it is possible to set it to a running process (I guess not) but you can grant the CAP_SYS_RESOURCE capability to an executable file using  `# setcap 'CAP_SYS_RESOURCE=+ep' /path/to/executable` (as super user).
In this example the `+ep` turns down into raise the `CAP_SYS_RESOURCE` capibility to be permitted and effective. However the man pages `capabilities(7)` and `setcap(8)` are useful sources for further information.

Answer (score 3):

you can change the ceiling on the maximum message size on this file /proc/sys/fs/mqueue/msgsize_max
I hope it works

Answer (score 1):

try the option RLIMIT_MSGQUEUE in function: int setrlimit(int resource, const struct rlimit *rlim);

man page: http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html

:)

Comment: I set with RLIM_INFINITY and still got "message too long" =/